# Azure Durable Orchestration timeout WaitForExternalEvent loses input because of polling times

Tags: c#, azure, azure-durable-functions

We have an Azure Orchestration that waits for an external event or a timeout. The timeout is 30 seconds. The problem is that the handling of the timeout happens around 20 seconds late consistently. This happens because of the polling interval.

Our issue now is that, if the input `AlarmCommand` happens between the timeout expiring and the actual function running (~20sec later), the input is lost.

This is an implementation from an official Microsoft doc example found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers?tabs=csharp#usage-for-timeout).

```cs
TimeSpan timeout = // 30 seconds
DateTime deadline = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(timeout);

using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
{
    var alarmTask = context.WaitForExternalEvent<AlarmMessage>("AlarmCommand");
    var timeoutTask = context.CreateTimer(deadline, cts.Token);
    _logger?.LogWarning($"Deadline: {deadline}");
    var winner = await Task.WhenAny(alarmTask, timeoutTask);

    if (winner == alarmTask)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        _logger?.LogWarning($"Input detected");
        // success
    }
    else
    {
        _logger?.LogWarning($"Timeout reached");
        // timeout
    }
};
```

[image]

The function is running late sometimes because of the way Azure polls Orchestrations. The timeout isn't triggered until the next polling happens. The problem is that any `AlarmCommand` input given between the timeout expiration and when the Orchestration actually triggers is lost.

How can we prevent `AlarmCommand` from being lost in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: I've not used durable functions, but I'm curious why you are using this method of determining a timeout when `CancellationTokenSource` does it for you?

Comment: You will only get a timeout message if winner does not equal alarmTask

Comment: The delay is at least partly caused by how timers work in DF. They are implemented with scheduled Storage Queue messages, and the runtime polls for new messages on some configurable interval. So it might not receive the message right away as the next poll needs to happen. I think it also might increase the polling time if no new messages arrive..

Comment: @DavidG because this is a durable function, and using CTS doesn't work.

Comment: @juunas interesting. So do you have a solution to my problem?

Comment: You could try tweaking the settings here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2C2x-durable-functions&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings. E.g. "maxQueuePollingInterval"

Comment: @juunas i tried setting the setting that you mentioned to 1 second but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durable Functions in Azure have a default `maxQueuePollingInterval` of 30 seconds. This means that the function won't notice any timers expiring until up to 30 seconds after the expiration time.

You could change the interval to 1 second. That way, the expired timeout will be handled up to 1 second instead of up to 30 seconds late.

Add the following to `host.json`

```
"extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
        "storageProvider": {
            "maxQueuePollingInterval": "00:00:01"
        }
    }
}
```